# back button of browser in spring security 3.2 + jsf

Tags: jsf, spring-security

How to prevent user from going back to the login page
after successful login using back button of browser in spring security 3.2 and jsf 
need custom filters? how to do ... 
help me 
​Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for the same problem, I disabled button back in browser:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
   window.history.forward();
   function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
```

Put this function in your welcome page.

Comment: but I do not want disabled button back in browser!
The standard solution is?